# Python error 'Can't convert expression to float'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, typeerror, sympy

I've looked through the lines of my code and can't find to see where my mistake is. Python Shows me that in my last line of the Code a 'Type Error' occured and can't convert an expression into float. I wanted to put the derivatives into an array and wanted to solve it for a specific value. In the attachment you can see the error message.

```
import sympy
from sympy import symbols
import math
import numpy as np
# Parameters
F = 1000 # Load [N]
rho = 7.8e-6 # Density [kg/mm^3]
l = 10[enter image description here][1]00      # length [mm]
a = 750 # lever arm [mm]
Smax = 200 # maximum bending stress (MPa)

# Symbolic variables
w,h = symbols('w h', positive =True)

# objective function
m = rho*l*w*h

# constraints
S = 6*F*a/(w*h**2) #  bending stress

w_bounds = [10, 50]
h_bounds = [10, 50]
# solve constraint 
h1 = sympy.solve(S - Smax, h)

# calculate gradient (constant for linear problem)
duW = sympy.diff(m,w)
duH = sympy.diff(m,h)
duDim = np.array([duW.subs(w, 25).evalf(), duH.subs(h, 25).evalf()], dtype ='float32')
```

Comment: `duW` is an expression using `h` (`0.0078*h`), so you need to give a value for h to get a numerical value for `duW` (`duW.subs(h, ...)`). Similar for `duH` and `w`. For more general formulas you might need to give values for both `h` and `w`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I defined w and h as symbolic variables, because they are my design variables for my optimization problem. By giving them a numerical value I can't solve my initial goal. Is there another way to solve to this ?

Comment: I thought that the evalf() is there to solve symbolic expressions

Comment: You need to interchange `h` and `w` in `duDim = np.array([duW.subs(h, 25).evalf(), duH.subs(w, 25).evalf()], dtype ='float32')`.   `duW.subs(w, 25)` doesn't change, it is still `0.0078*h` which will need a value for `h` to be evaluated. `evalf()` helps when an expression still contains formulas without symbolic variables.

Comment: Thank you, sir for helping me to understand where the problem is.